# Windows Multi-Touch Gestures

Tags: windows, drivers, boot-camp

Is there a driver or program that will emulate the four finger and three finger touch gestures when using Windows 7?  I really enjoy that functionality on OS X and would love to have Windows respond similarly.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer ([Samsung NP700](https://www.google.ch/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=samsung%20np700)) I can use features with finger gestures (1, 2, 3 or 4 fingers!)

This is possible through a software / driver named [Elan Smart Pad](http://www.emc.com.tw/eng/tpn_sp_fun.asp) ...

Now I'm just trying to configure shortcuts based on these gestures. Unfortunately they are predefined and can not be changed.

[Look at my post ..](https://superuser.com/questions/426796/windows-four-finger-swipe-for-spaces-deskspaces)

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension is out which enable Bootcampers to swipe back/forth with two fingers for pages. You can get it here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgegfjnccpnkdppohmfgnjalkediapkc

Or search for it yourself:
Swipe Gesture

In google addon store.

All credits goes to antimatter15.com for creating this. It's still at an early stage, but very useful indeed. And as seeing that swiping back/forth is one of the most used multi touch features (at least to my experience) this addon is a godsend. Also has no problem with people running virtual machines, as the addon can simply be turned off.