# Windows - Four-Finger Swipe for Spaces (Deskspaces)

Tags: windows

Is there a way to add a shortcut while dragging four fingers on the keyboard?

With [Elan Smart Pad](http://www.emc.com.tw/eng/tpn_sp_fun.asp), my computer can perform certain tasks by a slip of the fingers on the pad (mac style).

The problem is that I can not set these gestures. I wish I could assign a custom shortcut to a certain gesture (eg "ctrl + right" when you slide four fingers on the right).

My goal is to switch desktops with gestures (with [Deskpace](http://www.otakusoftware.com/deskspace/) Dexpot for example)

Concretely, how do I duplicate the functionality of an apple on windows (Four-Finger Swipe for Spaces)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found exactly what I needed!  (Requires Elan SmartPad )

This topic explains everything you need to do it. At least it worked with my Samsung NP700Z5C-S04

http://forum.notebookreview.com/samsung/711500-mac-like-four-finger-swipe-windows-8-np700z7c-s03-tutorial.html

This method require to manipulate registry but it's not bad.. It works just fine.

> First off there are requirements. I have only tested this with my pc
>   so I can't guarantee it for other laptops or even other versions of
>   windows on this laptop. But I'm guessing as long as you have Windows 8
>   (maybe 7) and an Elan (elantech) touchpad with at least 4 finger
>   multitouch, there's a good chance it'll work.
>
> First requirement: an Elan touchpad with at least 4 finger swipe. You
>   can either check online to find out, or possibly go into your Elantech
>   install directory (C:/Program Files/Elantech for me) and launch the
>   ETDDeviceInformation.exe. Hopefully it's there for you as it was for
>   me. That will tell you how many fingers it supports. Also any driver
>   MAY work, but I'm using the newest samsung NP700Z7C touchpad driver
>   available from Samsung's support website. My version is 11.7.2.1_WHQL.
>
> Next requirement: Dexpot 1.6.6, Build 2227. Other versions or builds
>   may work, but this is the one I'm using that I know works. This is a
>   free download from Dexpot | Virtuelle Desktops fÃ¼r Windows. It is the
>   program that enables multiple workspaces in windows.
>
> Third requirement: Windows 8. There is a very good chance 7 will work
>   fine but this is the one I know works. To be specific, Windows 8 Pro
>   64. Alright, onto the process.
>
> 1. Install Dexpot
> 2. Load registry editor and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Elantech/SmartPad. Make a backup of your
>      registry settings just in case. Make a backup of your whole OS if
>      possible. Do not change anything except what I specify. Be aware that
>      modifying your registry could make windows unusable so backup and be
>      careful if you're new at that.
> 3. Open your Elantech specific touchpad settings UI and set it aside.
> 4. Open the Dexpot settings and go to controls on the left.
> 5. Change the following key settings to the following values if not there already: FourFingerMove_Enable=0x00000001
>      FourFingerMove_Enable_Mode=0x00000000
>      FourFingerMoveLeft_Enable=0x00000001
>      FourFingerMoveLeft_Func=0x00000004
>      FourFingerMoveRight_Enable=0x00000001
>      FourFingerMoveRight_Func=0x00000003
> 6. Go to your mouse settings window you've opened and make a small change, and then change it back. This should force windows to
>      recognize the registry changes.
> 7. Go back into Dexpot's settings/controls section and open the "Switch desktop" list. Click on "Next desktop". Check "Allow hotkeys
>      without modifiers" and uncheck any modifiers. Then click in the
>      textbox underneath the modifiers. Perform a 4 finger swipe left or
>      right (depending on how you want it to function, I prefer left like
>      OSX). "Keycode 167" or "Keycode 166" should show up. Do the same with
>      "Previous desktop" but with the opposite swipe.
> 8. Click apply and try it out.
>
> If Keycode 167 or 166 did not show up then either your drivers or
>   hardware doesn't support it, or something got mixed up in the previous
>   steps. Check your drivers and retrace the steps.
>
> I'm really hoping this works for other people. I've searched high and
>   low for something like this and failed to find anything, so I hope
>   others can find this useful. If you try it and succeed please let me
>   know, especially if you're using a setup different than mine. If you
>   try and fail, let me know what didn't work and if I can think of
>   anything to help I will.
>
> Also it's not quite as fluid as OSX, but it's better than nothing in
>   my opinion. Also sometimes it doesn't work when certain programs are
>   loaded and have focus, click on the desktop and try again.
>
> Part 2: You can also enable a mac-like app expose to show all current
>   workspaces and applications on each, with the ability to drag windows
>   to other workspaces. To do this:
>
> Set FourFingerMoveUp_Enable to 1 and FourFingerMoveUp_Func to 9 (which
>   is pageup). Then go into the dexpot settings under controls/dexpot
>   components and set the "Window catalog (all desktops)" to shift and
>   then perform the swipe in the input box. Remember to change a setting
>   in the mouse settings gui quick to make windows recognize the registry
>   change.
>
> You can set this to whatever your comfortable with, it doesn't have to
>   be the shift key. But it should be something that most programs
>   wouldn't catch and interpret differently.
>
> Better yet, set the Func value to 4 again and just add a modifier. So
>   far nothing seems to use Keycode 167 for anything else. I think
>   technically it's supposed to be an internet forward/backward function
>   but it doesn't seem to have that effect in chrome for me, or anywhere
>   else. When setting a new key combination be sure to disable the
>   originals first or it will want to change desktops instead of setting
>   the value.